# How to implement the search operation for json shown in table view

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new in swift .I want implement the search operation for json show in table view about description field .

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell


       classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)
        //let image_url = filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
       // cell.sneakerImageView.image=filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image

        cell.newsTitle.text = classObject.descriptionn

        let imageURLPathString = newsurl + classObject.image

        let url1 = URL(string: imageURLPathString)
        print("xyz", url1)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!)

        if let imageData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.sneakerImageView.image = image
        }

        return cell


    }
```

here is the class that i have made for getting data from json

```
class getData: NSObject {

    var descriptionn : String = ""
    var image : String = ""

//    static let shared = getData()

    func getDataForTableView(results: [[String:String]], index : Int){

        var productArray = [String:String]()
        productArray = results[index]

            descriptionn = productArray["description"]!
            image = productArray["images"]!

    }
}
```

here is my search filter function about description field in table view

```
var filteredsneakernews = [String]()
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            // If we haven't typed anything into the search bar then do not filter the results

            if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
                filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn]
            } else {
                // Filter the results
                filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn].filter { $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }
            }
            self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

how to implement the search operation for json description field in table view .You can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HGQVN3QWFSQf1BcV-3Iv-pXOoWozcP1G/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

in the cellForRowAtindex you are populating results array of dict...
and after filtering u need to check data from results array but you are checking on get data object..

filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn].filter { $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) } instead of checking in this check on your data on results array

results = results.filter { $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }

like this

Comment: How to reload table view after search is complete and search bar is empty .                                  .......     func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredsneakernews = [classObject.descriptionn]
          self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()
        } ......this is not reloading the table view

Comment: then u need one more array for placeHolder..
declare a one more array as global name as placeHolderArray...
when u get data from json response assign placeHolderArray to results array . like this self.placeHolderArray = self.resultsArray...
after that when your search bar text is empty....
re-assign results array to placeHolderArray like this self.resultsArray = self.placeHolderArray....

Answer (score 0):

if you are following method search results display the tableview

```
class Model:NSObject {

var name1:String = ""
var size1:String = ""
var colour1:String = ""
var store1:String = ""



init (name:String, size:String, colour:String, store:String)
{

    self.name1 = name
    self.size1 = size
    self.colour1 = colour
    self.store1 = store


}


class func generatedModelArray () -> [Model] {

        var modelArray = [Model]()
        modelArray.append(Model(name: "Name0", size: "size0", colour: "colour0", store: "store0"))
        modelArray.append(Model(name: "name1", size: "size1", colour: "colour1", store: "store1"))
        modelArray.append(Model(name: "name2", size: "size2", colour: "colour2", store: "store2"))
        modelArray.append(Model(name: "name3", size: "size3", colour: "colour3", store: "store3"))

        return modelArray

    }
```

// Outlet connections and declaration

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
 var list = [Model]()
 var filterdArry = [Model]()

 var serachController = UISearchController()
 var resultController = UITableViewController()


//search
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

//viewDidLoad method

```
       searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true



    serachController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultController)
      tableview.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
       searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

      resultController.tableView.delegate = self
      resultController.tableView.dataSource = self




    let elm = Model(name: "Name0", size: "size0", colour: "colour0", store: "store0")
    list.append(elm)

    let elm1 = Model(name: "name1", size: "size1", colour: "colour1", store: "store1")
    list.append(elm1)

    let elm2 = Model(name: "name2", size: "size2", colour: "colour2", store: "store2")
    list.append(elm2)

    let elm3 = Model(name: "name3", size: "size3", colour: "colour3", store: "store3")
    list.append(elm3)

    filterdArry = list
    tableview.delegate = self
      tableview.dataSource = self
      tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "DetaisTableTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailsCell")
      self.view.addSubview(tableview)
      tableview.reloadData()
```

// Search Function

```
   func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
   filterdArry = list.filter({(mod) -> Bool in
    print("mod.name1\(mod.name1)")
    return mod.name1.lowercased().contains((searchController.searchBar.text)!.lowercased())

    })
     tableview.reloadData()
}
```

// Tableview methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
     if tableView == resultController.tableView  {
        return filterdArry.count
    } else {
        return list.count
    }


 }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailsCell") as! DetaisTableTableViewCell

    if tableView == resultController.tableView  {
        let model = filterdArry[indexPath.row]
         cell.label1.text = model.name1
    cell.label2.text = model.size1
    cell.label3.text = model.colour1
    cell.label4.text = model.store1
    } else {
       let model = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.label1.text = model.name1
    cell.label2.text = model.size1
    cell.label3.text = model.colour1
    cell.label4.text = model.store1
    }
   return cell
}


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")

   }
```

Comment: This method perfectly works. If you want to search function. please refer this method (Tableview)